# How do I debug work of 2sxc if Visual Query works perfectly during debug, but cshtml code can't access data?

Tags: debugging, 2sxc

I've edited some existing visual queries of Blog 4.0 application and when I was debugging it - it worked perfectly. But then on page it stopped working. Any attempt to use key with `Data` like `Data["Posts"]` raises `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException`. `App.Query["Blog Posts List"]["Posts"]` returns something, but any attempt to access its fields raises another exception (don't remember the name, but it said that there's no such member inside that object).
I didn't rename queries, I didn't change application settings. I just edited logic of 2 queries. I renamed 1 wiring endpoint name across 3 queries in whole chain.
How do I debug it? How can I see what does cshtml receive from database so I don't guess and put my crystal ball away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad: I confused two different files - `_List.cshtml` and `_List Paging.cshtml`. So I was searching for an error in the code of wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

In general, App.Query["Name of Query"] will get you the streams of data. You usually need to convert it using AsDynamic() or AsList() to something you can work with.

This should help some; [What is Data?](https://docs.2sxc.org/how-to/dynamic-code/object-data.html)

Comment: I found the source of error and answered my own question. It was my bad. But thanks for your answer anyway. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just running into problems with field names, you probably forgot the AsList or AsDynamic, just like @accuraty-jeremy mentioned.

For real debugging, go to insights, you'll see what happens - but in your case it probably won't help, because your working with an object that's not dynamic (so doesn't support .FirstName) until you AsList/AsDynamic it.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. `AsList(Data["Posts"])` causes `Error: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

Comment: I found the source of error and answered my own question. It was my bad. But thanks for your answer anyway. I appreciate it.